# loading PUTTY and open an SSH connection using within HTML

Tags: html, ssh, xhtml, putty

I  have been asked to create a webpage that has different links and depending on the link it will load putty and open an SSH connection.

I have never done this before so hoping that someone may be able to help me or guide me in the right direction.

I cannot find anywhere online where it shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ssh:` scheme in your URI:

```
<a href="ssh://@hostname">SSH to hostname</a>
```

It's up to the browser's configuration to know that it should run `Putty` to implement the `ssh:` scheme. Web browsers can't run local programs directly (except using ActiveX in Internet Explorer).

However, browsers may not actually support this. There was an Internet Draft specification for this URI scheme

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04

but it expired 8 years ago and was never made into an official standard.

Comment: when i run this it seems to just give me an error. it takes me to a page where it says page not displayed. my browser seems to not recognise the ssh or my browser is too dated to run this.